# Periodics "lags" in Embedded Linux application

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, lag

My team is working in an embedded Linux solution for a product where a center application receives and process data from the hardware and sends it to a database and to the interface application. In so doing, we are working with five threads:

1. Main Thread: create other threads and do some side processing (read data from the interface app, etc.)
2. UPP Thread: receives data from the hardware and put it in a buffer
3. DSP Thread: picks the data from the previous buffer and ask DSP processor to calculate with this data. Returned data is stored in a second buffer
4. DB Thread: After some time, picks a reasonable amount of calculated data and stores them in the file system.
5. Interface Thread: Picks current data and send to the interface app

This application can't miss any data pack coming by the UPP Thread, which gets new data each 200 ms. DSP Thread usually takes less then this 200 ms (for now it's taking ~30 ms, but in the future it will take more time). DB Thread is called normally once every 30 s and Interface thread is called in 5 Hz frequency.

The problem we are facing is that, from time to time, the threads take more time to do their job, specially the DB and the DSP threads. IOW, while the system works with a run of DSP per each run of UPP, some times the UPP is run up to 15 times without any call to DSP leaving to loss of data received. These sporadic "lags" in the threads occurs in all of them, but lags in the DB and Interface are not problematic, only when they ocurr in the UPP or DSP threads.

We check everything we could to try to find in our code where the problem lies without success - most of the time the system runs without any lags. We noticed some patterns, though:

- the lags are more prone to occur when the interface is running with one of the most "heavy" widgets visible.
- Nevertheless, the increase in required processing doesn't seems to be the cause: stressing the system with some "junk processing" AND the interface open didn't increase lag occurrence.
- It's probably not something directly related to the interface and that particular widget; all of its processing are similar in time (so any error would probably end being *non* randomic, which is not the case)

We are starting to think it's something with Linux. Normally, in day to day use of PCs, some lags with the mouse or the applications do occur and Linux may be doing this to us. We also thought about being the use of the RAM memory, shared between the main Omap L138 processor and the DSP processor, but some tests gave negative evidence to that hypothesis.

Do you have any suggestions? Could Linux really be the source of the problem? How could we know and how could we fix?

Any help will be appreciated.

P.s.: Same as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175635/little-slow-downs-in-embedded-linux-application)

Comment: Show your source code if you want some help. Did you `strace` and `oprofile` your application? "Linux be the source of the problem" does not mean much.

Comment: What do `top` or `ps auxw` and `free` says about your overall system?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the source code involved with this problem is gigantic, no way to copy and paste here =T I didn't use `strace` neither `oprofile`, but I'm considering using those in short time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `top` don't show much, since the lag is very quick. I don't know what should I expect from seeing `ps auxw`, since it just shows the running processes (everything OK when it comes to that). About `free`, general memory is OK.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit too basic, but it's the checklist of things I've considered when I've been dealing with bugs that relate to timing and design in the past.

**Specify what an acceptable lag is**

In the case of time sensitive applications, premature optimization can be hugely expensive, make sure you understand what your lag requirements are (have hard numbers), measure what you are observing, and keep improving until you reach your target.

**Pick appropriate Hardware**

Make sure that if you've got *n* threads, that you want reasonable timing for, that you've got about *n* cores. This makes it trivially easy to prove your process is under utilising the CPU. Even if you can't do this in production, doing this during testing can help rule out some types of bugs.

Make sure that your application won't use swap space - make sure you've got more than enough RAM for all possible use cases and run-times. Use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to make sure you're not leaking memory.

**Choose an appropriate embedded Linux**

The more timing critical your application is, the more likely it will be that you need an operating system that offers timing guarantees. Running on a true hard real-time operating system will give very different results to running on something that is just a stripped down desktop linux. Know and understand the implications of the embedded linux you have selected.

**Choose an appropriate priority level for you application**

If you're seeing sporadic lags, make sure that there isn't anything else running on your system that could be causing the problem. I've seen a few odd things on desktop Linux variants that can cause problems, including audio drivers.

At least during testing boost your priority to be much higher (lower value) than other background processes. You can use [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) to do this.

**Understand where your kernel calls occur**

As stated in the comments, use of a tool like [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to identify which kernel calls are being made is a very good idea. Similarly, some understanding of what types of [functions / operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Categories_of_system_calls) will trigger a system call can be very helpful (for example, where possible, reuse buffers rather than trigger frequent allocs and frees).

This also leads into understanding and minimising the locking your application is doing. This includes obvious things like acquiring locks in a consistent order, and minimising the time spent using locks, as well as adopting the lightest weight synchronization primitives that make sense (can you use atomics rather than mutexes?).

**Choose an appropriate scheduler and thread priorities**

Where you've got more tasks than cores, consider which scheduler you're using.

General purpose schedulers are (in most cases) not a good fit for performance critical applications. You linux distribution will provide some mechanism to change the [scheduler](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler) (although this may require elevate priviledges).

Round Robin scheduling (SCHED_RR) is a good start because it makes the CPU utilisation maths pretty easy to work out (at least to give a ballpark estimate). Make sure the threads with the tightest timing requirements have the highest priority. Be aware that changing priorities can cause some subtle bugs ([priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion))

**Lock your performance critical threads to specific cores**

You can do this using an operating system (or platform specific) call to set the thread affinity (the need to stay on a particular core) [sched_affinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity). In some cases, this can help ensure consistent cache performance